# Difference between a method called with a parameter and a method called with none

Tags: flutter, dart, methods, conditional-operator, method-parameters

please what's the difference between a method called with a parameter and one called with no parameter example:

```
state is! LoginInProgress ? _onLoginButtonPressed : null,
```

and:

```
state is! LoginInProgress ? _onLoginButtonPressed(): null,
```

these two statements have different functionalities in my code execution, **_onLoginButtonPressed** and **_onLoginButtonPressed()** i mean, please I would really apricate if I can get the difference between the two, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When a method has a parameter and it requires a variable to perform the method thus its just like when your mom asks you to go out for shopping but you have arguments that you need money and a hello kitty bag to perform that task. For example : Let's say a method called a go_for_shopping requires two variables to perform its task, if we don't provide the integers it will give you an error.

`void go_for_shopping(string hello_kitty_bag, int money){ return hello_kitty_bag + money;` }

But when you set no parameters it will perform the task without any arguments when you call that method.

Comment: thanks for this answer, understood it a lot better from the previous answers... thanks for contribution anyways, happy coding

Comment: By the way I an just 14 I don't know anything

Answer (score 0):

To be clear `_onLoginButtonPressed` seems to be of type `void Function()` and you trying to set callback to some widget (we have no full snippet - so I'm trying to guess)

Functions are objects in Dart - you can pass function as argument and call it later

1. This `_onLoginButtonPressed` returns Function object - you not calling this function, you just send it elsewhere
2. When this `_onLoginButtonPressed()` calls that function and returns void(nothing)

In second case you will get error when you try use result

> This expression has a type of ‘void’ so its value can’t be used.

Comment: thanks a lot, I understand this better now... happy coding,

Comment: sorry for not clarifying my code, _onLoginButtonPressed is of type dynamic

Comment: You can call only Funtions and Callable classes(implements call()) - so I it's surely Function type =)

Answer (score 0):

in this case, its not whether one of the methods has a `parameter` or not but rather if you put the `parenthesis` or not.
When you use the `parenthesis` in a method, you are evoking it. (running the function).

`state is! LoginInProgress ? _onLoginButtonPressed(): null,`  << runs the function

`state is! LoginInProgress ? _onLoginButtonPressed : null,`  << doesn't run the function

to make it more clear:

`dynamic storeFunction = _onLoginButtonPressed;`  << stores the function on the variable `storeFunction`

`dynamic storeFunctionResult = _onLoginButtonPressed();` << runs the function and stores the result returned by it on the `storeFunctionResult` variable (if return type is not `void`)

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, this makes total sense in relation to how my code was behaving...

Comment: sorry I can't upvote you, I don't have up to 15 reputation

Comment: don't worry, no problem